# Adding a specific value from UWP to database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, uwp

[Picture of my UWP UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdoSi.png)

I am facing this problem where I only want to insert a value into a database. In this case, I want to insert the "number of times" value into the database. How do I do it ?

Example, once a person complete the exercise, the "number of times" will be inserted into the database.

```
string myConnectionString = "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=root;database=bluetooth;SslMode=None;charset=utf8";

try {
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
    connection.Open();

    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) {
        txtTest.Text = "It is connected.";
    } else {
        txtTest.Text = "It is NOT connected.";
    }      
} catch (MySqlException ex) {

}
```

I have wrote a simple code to test the connection to my database.

Answer (score 1):

First you will definitely need a table where you will store the data, so you will need to execute a `CREATE TABLE` query.

Then you will either do `INSERT INTO table` or `UPDATE table` query to set the data according to your requirements.

All this is using built-in [`MySqlCommand` type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-mysqlcommand.html). I recommend you to check out the [documentation on the MySQL homepage](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming.html) for simple examples and tutorials.

Comment: I have created a table but Idk how to insert the data into my table

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html